# Single Sign On for wordpress multisite with different domains

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, config, multisite

I am trying to get SSO working for a WordPress multi-site environment with several domains. I tried to send all sites to the same database

```
define('CUSTOM_USER_TABLE',      'wp_users');
define('CUSTOM_USER_META_TABLE', 'wp_usermeta');

define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/');
define( 'COOKIE_DOMAIN', 'Site1.com' );
define('COOKIEPATH', '/');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '');
```

This works on the main domain but when I try to login to one of the other domains I get a cookies blocked or not supported error.

I also tried this:

```
define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/');
define( 'COOKIE_DOMAIN', '' );
define('COOKIEPATH', '');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '');
```

But this will only let you login to the domains separately, so you can login at site1 but be logged out at site2. But I want them both to be logged in.